# Painting Some Images into a Pane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics

I'm trying to make a program that will let you pick the number of images you want, it will then ask what the names of the files you want to use are. Then it will print them in the appropriate fashion on the screen in a grid.

Now I know many parts of this code like the width and height, rows and columns, and other things are wrong, I intend to fix them after I figure this bit out. It's not letting me use paintComponent no matter how I change it. I want to keep this in my main class, is this still possible? Often times I put it in a separate graphics class, but bringing in my inputs to that class is irritating.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Core extends JPanel{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many selections will you have? 1, 2 or 4? ");
        if(r.next().contains("1") | r.next().contains("2") | r.next().contains("4")){
        String selections = r.next();
        int number = Integer.parseInt(selections);
        ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList();
        for(int j = 1; j <= number; j++){
            System.out.println("Your options are boo, bae, skinny, bro...");
            System.out.println("Name of image " + j + "? ");
            if(r.next().contains("boo") | r.next().contains("bae") | r.next().contains("skinny") | r.next().contains("bro"))
            images.add(r.next());
            else{
                System.out.println("Im sorry that was an improper input...");
                System.out.println("Next time, remember, you can only input boo, bae, skinny, or bro.");
                r.close();
            }
        }

        JFrame theGUI = new JFrame();
        theGUI.setTitle("Random Images");
        theGUI.setSize(number * 100, number * 100);//ratio of 1:100
        theGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container pane = theGUI.getContentPane();

        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(number, number));
        for(int j = 1; j <= number; j++){
            Color backColor = Color.white;
            Image  image = new ImageIcon((images.get(j)) + ".jpg").getImage();
            public paintComponent(Graphics g){//error here(paintComponent cannot be resolved to a variable)(Illegal modifier for 'g')
                super.paintComponent(Graphics g);//and error here (cannot use super)(Graphics cannot be resokved to a variable)

            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100, null);}
            ColorPanel panelz = new ColorPanel(backColor);
            pane.add(panelz);
        }


        theGUI.setVisible(true);
        }//end of the checker for the 1, 2 and 4.

        else {
            System.out.println("I'm sorry that was an improper input.");
            System.out.println("Keep in mind your inputs may only be 1, 2 or 4.");
        }
    }

}
```

Apologies for posting code in the comments, I'm new here. But when i do like you say, what do i put for the variable declare id?

```
public class Core extends JPanel{

    public static Image image;

    public void paintComponent(g){//insert VariableDeclaratorID error
        super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
```

Comment: You are declaring the method inside of your main method, which isnt proper ayntax. Declare it outside of your main method, but still inside your class

Comment: @VinceEmigh Alright lemme run that through real quick and try that...

Comment: In fact you've get **everything** inside of your main method and nothing in the class proper. I suggest 1) you read the Swing graphics tutorials (or re-read them), read up on OOP and Java, and then re-try this thing from scratch. Understand that the main method should be **very** short, and should just get the program running and that's it.

Comment: You can find links to the Swing tutorials and other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing)

Comment: You're trying to override a method within a method...

Comment: It is still saying 'Graphics' isn't recognized. @VinceEmigh

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I understand how that works, how a main method is supposed to be organized, and while I am iffy on how Swing graphics work, I have read through the articles that oracle has posted on their site about it. I do not want to add a separate class especially with such a short program. My teacher said we can do it in what class and that's what she asked, this is the only issue I'm running into. Typically when I choose how to write something, yes, I keep the main method brief.

Comment: @Kotite: Regardless you're going about this all wrong. But if you change your code and find problems, post the new code. My main recommendation is to scrap this code, read the tutorials -- or re-read them, and re-start without making wild guesses. And yes, keep it brief here as well. You have to do the work in the class, that's how Swing component painting works. You have no choice.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, got that, Vince beat you to it. But this doesn't answer my question mate.

Comment: Which one doesn't answer your question?

Comment: You need to import `Graphics` at the top of your filw, below the package declaration (if one exists): `import java.awt.Graphics;`

Comment: @VinceEmigh: he already imports this.

Comment: @VinceEmigh The method has no return type `public (something, someting, something, ???) paintComponent(Graphics g) {`...which is outlined in my answer...

Comment: Ah, didn't see that. You're declaring the method inside of a forloop, still within the main method.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well your answer will work, and I understand how to print the images OUTSIDE of my main method. My homework calls for me to do this in one class, otherwise I would create a class called ColorPanel and then have it extend JPanel and do this:

Comment: import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ColorPanel extends JPanel{
 public ColorPanel(Color backColor){
  setBackground(backColor);
 }
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
 super.paintComponent(g);
  //I'll draw the images here
 }

}

Comment: @Kotite: so do it in one class -- have that class extend JPanel, give it a `paintComponent(...)` method, and all the behaviors and fields it needs, and then in the main method, create your instance, put it in a JFrame and display the JFrame. What's the issue? No one is telling you that you must use many classes, but we are suggesting that you do at least some of your important coding in the instance world not in the static main world.

Comment: Kottie, look into what methods are and how to declare them. Thatll help you understand

Comment: It wont let me insert code, but anyways I get how to do that guys, seriously! I don't need tutorials about inheritance and Swing and GUI's I understand how to do these things. My only issue is doing this in ONE class, I don't know how. How to use user input with drawing images, all in one class. This baffles me.

Comment: Re-read my last comment above. Please.

Comment: You are doing within one class, the `main` METHOD is a METHOD of your `Core` CLASS which extends `JPanel`...I don't see the issue

Comment: public class Core extends JPanel{
 
 public static Image image;
 
 public void paintComponent(g){//insert VariableDeclaratorID error
  super.paintComponent(g);
 
 return g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100, null);
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args){

Comment: The error when i do that is that i need to insert a variable declarator, idk what that would be for paintcomponent, since it doesn't matter what the variable is it will always do the same thing right?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments since it loses its formatting making it unreadable. Instead, post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26770030/edit).

Comment: There I did as you said and I removed the return, I'm sorry I'm listening to 3 or 4 people and I've just realized Vince is no help. I didn't think I needed a return either, my bad. But what do I put as my VDID the ... in your comment? @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You're trying to override a method within a method.  Not only is this illegal in Java, it's not how painting in Swing is done.
2. You've not provided a return type of the `paintComponent` method
3. When calling a method, you don't need to declare the parameter type `super.paintComponent(Graphics g);`, just pass the instance of the right type of object to it, `super.paintComponent(g);`
4. Don't mix console based input with GUI input.  GUI's run in an event driven environment, this makes them non-linear in nature and makes it difficult to collect information from the user at the command line while the UI is running.

Before you go any further, take a look at:

- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)
- [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)
- [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) (which would be easier then custom painting the images)

Take this...

```
public paintComponent(Graphics g){    error here(paintComponent cannot be resolved to a variable)(Illegal modifier for 'g')
    super.paintComponent(Graphics g);    and error here (cannot use super)(Graphics cannot be resokved to a variable)

g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100, null);}
```

Out of your `for-loop` and make it a method of your `Core` class...

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // ^--- Need this...
    super.paintComponent(g);
                      // ^--- Don't need Graphics, just an instance of it...
}
```

`main` is NOT a class, it is a method, a method of `Core` ;)

For example...

```
public class Core extends JPanel{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //..
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(number, number));
        for(int j = 1; j <= number; j++){
            Color backColor = Color.white;
            Image  image = new ImageIcon((images.get(j)) + ".jpg").getImage();
            // This be bad...
            //public paintComponent(Graphics g){//error here(paintComponent cannot be resolved to a variable)(Illegal modifier for 'g')
            //    super.paintComponent(Graphics g);//and error here (cannot use super)(Graphics cannot be resokved to a variable)
            //
            //g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100, null);}
            ColorPanel panelz = new ColorPanel(backColor);
            pane.add(panelz);
        }


        theGUI.setVisible(true);
        //...
    }

    // This be better...
    @Override   
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // Draw the List of images here how ever you want...
    }

}
```

**Updated...**

Okay, if I understand your comments, what you want to do is create an instance of `JPanel`, but provide a custom implementation of it's `paintComponent` method for EACH image...

```
for(int j = 1; j <= number; j++){
    Color backColor = Color.white;
    final Image  image = new ImageIcon((images.get(j)) + ".jpg").getImage();
 // ^--- This is important
    panel.add(new JPanel() {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, yes I get what you're saying here, the thing is I need these images to be drawn 1 image to 1 panel, and then printed in a pane. Since the program relies upon what images you wanted and how many. Would that still work with the method being used outside the main like that? (I'm looking at your brackets to gauge where the main method ends.)

Comment: Okey Dokey. I'm sure my code is fuddled and messed up XD. As I said alot of the widths columns etc arent right and its a mess of stuff. Basically it takes input of number of images: 1, 2, or 4. And lets you pick the images you want. Then draw them in that order, in a either 1x1 2x2 or 1x2 way.

Comment: Just missed the point about needing to put each image within it's own `JPanel`...still think a `JLabel` would be easier, but if that's what you're required to do ;)

Comment: Okay rad, last thing that I'm getting as an error is where you do image.getWidth() and image.getHeight() it says i need to put an imageobserver. I don't know why it's asking, it should be going to image to get these, it shouldn't need an observer right? Here I'm clueless so point me to any tutorials if you wanted and I won't give you grief XDDDD

Comment: Sorry, my test code was using `BufferedImage`, use `image.getWidth(this)` instead, do the same for `image.getHeight` :P

Comment: Thanks! Especially for dealing with my agro, sorry coding can piss me off alot, I'm not great at it T.T

Comment: You should hear me swearing at the screen ;)